# Force other apps to lauch my app first

Tags: android, android-intent

The use case:

I want my kids to do some extra home work before they can play their favorite games on the phone. So, when they try to lauch these apps, I want my app to be lauched first. Only after they have finished certain tasks, say a couple of multiple choice questions, can they close my app and continue to their intended apps.

Is this possible to implement in Android? How?

Comment: I dont think so. An app that blocks other apps could have some harmful intentions

Comment: No, this is not possible unless you hack the Android OS. I would suggest you to write your own OS for this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you have to used rooted permission like System to achieve above functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this -- not with an app, but with a custom launcher.  You could create a launcher that knows which apps are the "fun" apps and which are the "learning" apps.

Do a search on "android build custom launcher" to get started in the right direction.

Comment: Sounds doable. Thanks.